# Continue another test where the previous one ends in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Is it possible to continue another test on place, where the previous one ends?

I mean... I have some tests. First one test is testing a login functionality. Another one is testing some stuff in the user panel. But this last one again go trought the login. So, is it possible, that first test runs, checks login funcionality and then another one is continuing its 'job'?

Answer (score 0):

If the driver instance is shared between tests, then yes.  You need to design your tests in a way that the

1. Second test should depend on first test to guarantee order.
2. Driver should not quit after first test
3. Driver init code shouldn't execute before second test

However, it is better to code independent tests.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. I know it is better, but it is also really annoying to wait about 30 minutes to complete some tests.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Assuming:

- They're in the same test fixture
- Driver is shared
- The "30 minutes" in your comment to the previous answer is due to the log in process, not the verification of login

You could add an if statement to the second test to verify that login has been done.  If that hasn't been done, then just call the login method.  This saves duplicating the login code.

```
[Test]
public void LoginTest() {
  login();
  bool isLoggedIn = loginVerification();
  Assert.IsTrue( isLoggedIn );

[Test]
public void UserPanelTest() {
  bool isLoggedIn = loginVerification();
  if( !isLoggedIn ) {
    login();
  }
  //The rest of your test
}

private void login() {
  //Code to log in
}

private bool loginVerification() {
  bool isLoggedIn;
  //Some code to check if login was successful
  return isLoggedIn;
}
```

**Option 2:**

Do the log in in a TestFixtureSetUp, then only do your verification in the login test.

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void FixtureSetUp() {
  //Rest of setup
  login();
}

[Test]
public void LoginTest() {
  bool isLoggedIn = loginVerification();
  Assert.IsTrue( isLoggedIn );

[Test]
public void UserPanelTest() {
  //Code for this test
}

private void login() {
  //Code to log in
}

private bool loginVerification() {
  bool isLoggedIn;
  //Some code to check if login was successful
  return isLoggedIn;
}
```